# Why cant I use an Iterator this way?

Tags: java

```
Iterator<String> iterator=...

//right way
for (Iterator<String> i = iterator; i.hasNext(); ){
    System.out.println(i.next());
}

//why can't?
for(String i:iterator){         
}
```

**Reference:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do more compactly:

```
for(String i:list){
}
```

The syntax is only for Iterables (and arrays), not for their Iterators directly (and also not for Enumerations).

Why not? I don't know... Maybe too much complexity/effort (in the compiler implementation) for a "rare" case. Or edge-cases that would cause trouble (such as an Iterable that is also an Iterator, I think some people make such beasts).

Maybe try libraries like Google Guava to get some more convenient ways to work with Iterators, Collections, and friends.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler checks the syntax for the for enhanced and requires that the expression after the colon returns an object that implements the Iterable interface. Iterator doesn't implement it.

Comment: does array implement `Iterable` interface?like: `for(int i:new int[]{1,2,3}){...`

Comment: `for (Integer i : Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}) {...`

Comment: Nope, its not assignable to a Iterable reference, but that is a special case. The compiler knows and depending whether it is an array or an Iterable you can traverse it. So you can use an array or a class that implements Iterable.

Comment: @pap `for(int i:new int[]{1,2,3}){...` is work,Do not need `Arrays.asList`

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the for loop syntax with objects that implement the Iterable interface.

Iterators are not iterable.

Answer (score -1):

```
    for(String i:list){
        //
    }
```